# ASP.NET MVC 3 RC VS10-KB2385361-x86 error (freezing)

Tags: installation, asp.net-mvc-3

I think I'm cursed in some way... I had errors while installing MVC 3 beta. and now the same thing with MVC 3 RC. I've read about this problem here : http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/09/asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx. But after uninstalling all the mvc-beta-nuget-asppages stuff I have the same thing hanging - this **VS10-KB2385361-x86** error. 
I'm on Win7 x64, and using VS 2010 x64. What might be the solution to all this? (I don't want to reinstall the whole VS because of it).

OK. I've managed to install it (after 2 days trying). 
Here is what I've done:

- Uninstalled ASP.NET MVC 3 run-time components,ASP.NET Web Pages run-time components. (doesn't work after this);
- Reinstalled VS 2010 ( still freezes);
- Launched VS (just did some work, nothing special, just writing code), then I tried installing MVC 3 RC again (it got frozen), after a while I launched installer again having the firs one opened (it prompted some message saying another installation is running), and some real **magic** happened because first installer suddenly started working and installed whole thing.

Don't know how it works, but everything is running well (so far).

Comment: well, I did reinstall VS and still no success.

Comment: It does not hang. You just have to be patient. Just leave it running overnight. There was a similar problem with WP7 installer, took 1 person 20 hours to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem yesterday, but i resolve it today, ohye

1、unzip AspNetMVC3Setup.exe to a folder

2、In  the AspNetMVC3Setup folder, you can install aspnetwebpages.msi and aspnetmvc3.msi and other install

I am a chinese ,so I english is not good, I found other people has the same prblem, hope you can tell them

Comment: Yeah. This is a good. Idea. So Just install one by one all of the things included and skip the vs10-kb2385361-x86 file. I guess this hould work. I can't try it coz it's working now.

Comment: I strongly recommend against skipping that installer. That installer is required to get full Razor support in Visual Studio, including syntax highlighting, Intellisense, and more.

Comment: Any ideas how to get VS10-KB2385361-x86 to install?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to it needing the visual studio cdrom. If you installed from MSDN mount the iso and it should work. Just tested this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 7 32-bit on the first attempt, but it worked on the second try with no changes to the system. If you see this issue it's worth retrying at least one more time before trying other things.